# Problem with negative lookbehind regex capturing

Tags: php, regex, negative-lookbehind

I try to match email addresses but only when they are not preceeded with "mailto:". I try this regular expression:

`"/(?<!mailto:)[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})/"`

against this string:
`'<a href="mailto:someemail@domain.com">EMAIL</a>  ...   otheremail@domain.com '`

I would expect to catch only `'otheremail@domain.com'`, but I also receive `'omeemail@domain.com'` - see missing `'s'`. I wonder what's wrong here. Can't I have a normal regex after the lookbehind assertion?

My whole example in PHP looks like:

```
$testString = '<a href="mailto:someemail@domain.com">EMAIL</a>  ...   otheremail@domain.com ';
$pattern = "/(?<!mailto:)[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})/";
preg_match_all($pattern, $testString, $matches);
echo('<pre>');print_r($matches);echo('</pre>');
```

Thank you!

Comment: You don't want to use a HTML parser?

Comment: You should escape the `-` in your regex -> e.g. `[_a-z0-9\-]`.

Comment: @Peter: Not necessary as it is not part of a valid range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because after `s` there is a string that matches your regex, `omeemail@domain.com`, and because `s` is hardly `mailto:` it matches. Getting a word boundary in there will work for most cases:

Change:

```
(?<!mailto:)
```

To:

```
(?<!mailto:)\b
```

On a side note: use example.com for examples, domain.com is owned by an actual company.

Comment: Tsssk, isn't it obvious? Will do :P

Comment: The `\b` prevents the email address from starting in the middle of a word. Before hand `omeemail@domain.com` was valid, because it was preceeded by a `s` and not `mailto:`.

Answer (score 2):

It tries to match at "someemail@", but fails because it's immediately preceded by "mailto:", so then it tries to match at "omeemail@", which succeeds because it's not immediately preceded by "mailto:".

EDIT: It think that changing `(?<!mailto:)` to `(?!mailto:)` works best.

@Wrikken: The regex permits "." in the email address, but if you have `(?<!mailto:)\b` then "mailto:some.email@" will be matched from "email@".

Comment: Hmmm... That's right, \b is not so perfect solution. But still why do you suggest switching to negative lookahead? It's also not a perfect one. I guess it would be best to use something instead of \b

Comment: Can you give an example where a negative lookahead will fail?

Comment: @MRAB Hmm, you're right, was a bit hasty and it's late... All thing considered we could ofcourse require it starts with `(^|\s|>)`, but then I think alex's original comment about using a HTML parser becomes more and more attractive.

Comment: @Wrikken: I agree. Regex isn't always the best tool.

Comment: I came up with my own "email boundary", the whole regex goes as follows:  
`"/(?<!mailto:)(?<=[^A-Za-z0-9_.+@])[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})/"`  

What do you think of it?

Comment: @boryn: just for the heck of it, I'd add an `|^` to your postive lookbehind.

Comment: @Wrikken: Sorry, this is my first question here ever! Please forgive me :)

Comment: @Wrikken: I didn't include `|^` as after `mailto:` it can't be at the beginning

Comment: @boryin: But you state that it _doesn't_ start with `mailto:`... If you'd be so kind as to un-accept my answer, so I can remove my blemish on SO's pages :)

Comment: @wrikken: You are perfectly right! Eg. it is necessary with this string: `'theemail@example.com ... <a href="mailto:so.meemail@example.com">EMAIL</a>  ...   othe.remail@example.com'`

Answer (score 0):

So with tips from @Wrikken and @MRAB we come up with the final and working regex:
`"/(?<!mailto:)(?<=^|[^A-Za-z0-9_.+@-])[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})/"`

The important thing was to use a lookahead serving as an "email boundary" after the negative lookbehind.